# When should the tabularx environment be used or not?

Tags: tabularx

I asked a question here and [egreg replied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467574/138900) that the tabularx environment was not the right tool. He solved the problem with the tabular environment. 
[Werner didn't](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467567/138900) use it either.
In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468358/138900) Mico also says that the tabularx environment is not suitable.

I thought the tabularx environment was adapted to get columns of the same width, but this can be done in the tabular environment as [egreg did](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467560/how-to-change-only-the-color-of-numbers-and-not-units-with-numprint#comment1176015_467574).

1. Is the tabularx environment useful?
2. When should we use the tabularx environment?
3. Do you have any examples where this environment is useful?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is the tabularx environment useful?

Yes. But it's no environment intended to replace `tabular` with (i.e. it makes no sense to make every tabular a tabularx).

> When should we use the tabularx environment?

You should use it when you need to calculate the width of a column with respect to a total width. Please note that if your columns are short and do not contain line breaks you do not gain anything from using `tabularx`. You can get fixed-width columns with regular `p` or `wl` specifiers.

> Do you have any examples where this environment is useful?

- When you need to reproduce word processor tables it's quite useful as they are often using equally-sized columns.
- When you are going to have several columns which should be of equal-size and which will have line breaks.
- When you are in a hurry and do not want to do calculations.

Answer (score 17):

TeXnician already said when it's useful, I would like to add when it is detrimental.

Never use `tabularx` without an `X` column!

Sometimes I saw questions with this wrong usage here, never do that!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}  

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}\centering 
\caption{Here it is useful} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xcc} 
\toprule
Column A & Column B & Column C \\ 
\midrule
\texttt{tabularx} is useful when there is one (or more) columns with long text which goes on more than one row & lions & ducks \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering 
\caption{\label{tab:awful}Here it is useless and a bit awful (you only have short text in columns, there is too much blank space left)} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}} 
\toprule
Column A & Column B & Column C \\ 
\midrule
marmots & lions & ducks \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering 
\caption{\label{tab:wrong}Here it is detrimental and horrible (never use \texttt{tabularx} without an X column)} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccc} 
\toprule
Column A & Column B & Column C \\ 
\midrule
marmots & lions & ducks \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering 
\caption{Instead of Table \ref{tab:awful} or Table \ref{tab:wrong}, this one is much better} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
\toprule
Column A & Column B & Column C \\ 
\midrule
marmots & lions & ducks \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lions and ducks? Is that a good idea? After all, lions are cats and ducks are birds ;)

Comment: @TeXnician But I put them in separate columns :)

Comment: I'm normally against vertical lines in columns, in this specific case they might be useful to keep the ducks and marmots safe -- we don't want the lions to eat them, do we? :)

Comment: @samcarter We have found a proper use of vertical rules, lol!

Answer (score 14):

The important thing to note about `tabularx` that it is all about automatically setting the target length for *line breaking* within a column. However the vast majority of data tables in scientific documents are (apart from the headings) tables of numerical data where there is no line breaking within the column, so I would say that `tabularx` is not suitable for those cases.

An `X` column is a `p` column of an automatically determined width, but like any `p` column it is a `\parbox` designed for paragraphs of text wrapped to the specified width.